# find duplicate in first field, then combine text from second field of duplicate lines

Tags: awk

I have file.csv with two fields similar to this:

```
text,something
more,somethingelse
text,another
foo,bar
```

I sort the file so that everything in the first field is in order so that all the duplicates in the first column are grouped together.

```
foo,bar
more,somethingelse
text,something
text,another
```

What I need to do but can't figure out is to move the text in the second field to same line as the duplicate in the first field, separated by a ";". It doesn't matter what order the second field is entered. I just want the output to be something like this:

```
foo,bar
more,somethingelse
text,something; another
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work. Not surprising since I'm just learning awk.

```
sort file.csv | awk 'BEGIN{last = ""; value = 0;} {if ($1 == last) {print $0, "; value";}}'
```

I wanted 'last' to hold the value of the first field of the previous line and 'value' to hold the value of the second field of the previous line. But i couldn't figure out how to make that work.

Is it possible to do this with a shell script? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work without the need for `sort`:

```
awk -F, '{
    lines[$1] = (lines[$1] ? lines[$1] "; " $2 : $0)
}
END {
    for (line in lines) print lines[line]
}' file
more,somethingelse
text,something; another
foo,bar
```

- Set the input field separator to `,`.
- Check if the column1 exists in our line array. If it is then pad the second column separated by `;`.
- If the column1 is not present in our array assign the entire line as value
- In the `END` block iterate through our array and print the values.